# How can we disable the default keypad of textbox in silverlight windows phone 7?

Tags: windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7

i have made my custom keypad so i want to enter the text with my custom keypad. But the problem is that every time when textbox get focus the default keypad pops up.
so how can i fix this or i have to have to opt some patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible, as the SIP is controlled by the OS, and is shown depending on whether you have a hardware keyboard or not. If you really want to have a custom keypad, you will probably need to design your own data entry controls as well (ie. custom textbox that shows your SIP).

Comment: can u tell me how to design custom textbox and then handle the SIP

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it the "elegant" way. If you really need this you could build the following:
1. User touches the control (control has focus ... open your custom SIP)
2. immediately switch the focus to a hidden, non textbox control
3. OS SIP will not show if this is done fast enough

Sorry, this is the only way I am aware of :(

A related example: http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet5650.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, in this release anyways. I have also run into a problem with using the default keypad. But there are some options to use a keyboard that is designed for different types of input (ex. Search, Text, etc.).

Check out [this article](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/post/31-Days-of-Windows-Phone-7c-Day-10-InputScope-TextBoxes.aspx). It gives quite a few options in wp7 when it comes to the keypad. I'm sure one of these could be usefull.

All you have to do is set the `InputScope = ""` in the textbox control to whatever scopes are available(check article ^).

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the IsReadOnly property of the testBox to true

Comment: sorry i can't do that because i have to show the cursor postion also and more over user should feel that he is having control on textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Its an Interesting task .

I remember , i did the similar task with Windows Mobile 6  / 5 and Pocket PC 2003 where we have the access to the native API's via pInvoke and disabled the SIP Button . like using SHFullScreen

I think this is not supported in Windows Phone 7 since it is purely managed code .

Comment: Is there some other way to do so. How abt making textbox as custom control. I haven't made any custom control yet so can u tell me abt any link or something to do so.